# How To Loop Every Line In TextArea With Other TextArea

Tags: php, html

Basically, I've two 3 textareas
Like That:

```
First textarea:
test
test2
test3
Second textarea:   
fizz
fizz2
fizz3
Third textarea:
buzz
buzz2
buzz3
```

I Want the loop to take the first line of the first textarea and print it with the first line of second textarea and first line of third textarea
Example:

```
test => fizz => buzz
test => fizz => buzz2
test => fizz => buzz3

test => fizz2 => buzz
test => fizz2 => buzz2
test => fizz2 => buzz3

test => fizz3 => buzz
test => fizz3 => buzz2
test => fizz3 => buzz3
```

Then when it print Like That It heads to the next line in the first textarea `test2` and prints the same thing.
I've been using this code put not working, I think the whole problem in where to put the increment but I tried a lot of lines

```
    $ta1 = explode(PHP_EOL, $valid);
    $xx = 0;
    $yy = 0;
    $zz = 0;
    foreach ($ta1 as $key => $value) {
        $ta = $ta1[$xx];
            $usr = explode(PHP_EOL, $users);
            foreach ($usr as $key => $value) {
                $user = $usr[$yy];
                $pwd = explode(PHP_EOL, $passwords);
                $yy++;
                foreach ($pwd as $key => $value) {
                    $pass = $pwd[$zz];
                    echo "F: $ta User: $user Password: $pass" . "<br>";
                    $zz++;
                    $xx++;
```

Comment: Why not just use a `for` loop to begin with, then you _got_ a loop index already, that you can use to access the data in all three arrays.

Comment: exploding these other arrays inside nested loops makes very little sense to begin with. Explode all three of them first, then use a for loop to access the items in each one.